# Call a Spider's method from Pipeline - Python Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

This is Spider

```
class TicketsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def __set_last_start_date(self, dateString):
        #code here
```

This is Pipeline

```
class TicketsPipeline(object):

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        spider.__set_last_start_date(spider.lastAdScrapedDate)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline
```

I want to call `__set_last_start_date()` function from `spider_closed()` method.  But I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 149, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
  File "tickets/pipelines.py", line 236, in spider_closed
    spider.__set_last_start_date(spider.lastAdScrapedDate)
AttributeError: 'TicketsSpider' object has no attribute '_TicketsPipeline__set_last_start_date'
2016-12-13 02:49:53 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

I can assure you that I can get `spider.lastAdScrapedDate` but I am unable to call `spider.__set_last_start_date`

Comment: Are you able to call any other spider method? Is `__set_last_start_date` correctly defined? Maybe you need to investigate with a debugger

Comment: I can get `spider.lastAdScrapedDate` but I am unable to call `spider.__set_last_start_date`

Comment: I'm talking about methods, not attributes. Why would the error mention `_TicketsPipeline__set_last_start_date` and not `'TicketsSpider' object has no attribute '__set_last_start_date'`? Try with pdb

Comment: @paultrmbrth `spider.__get_last_start_date()` is also giving same error ... I am not expert in Python and Debugging Python ... what could be reason for this error as first thought?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Names, in a class, with double underscore leading  are intended to be private.

> Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python) for detail.

option 1. You can rename your method name, not use double underscore leading.

option 2. If you want to keep your method name, then call it in this way, but I don't think it's a good idea:

```
    def close_spider(self, spider):
        spider._TicketsSpider__set_last_start_date(spider.lastAdScrapedDate)
```

Comment: Thanks @pennyliangliping, I had no idea that double-underscore did that.

Comment: @pennyliangliping never thought of that :P